# Is there a way to give dynamic timeouts to Rest Template?

Tags: spring-boot, connection-pooling, resttemplate, completable-future, spring-webclient

I am using Spring Rest template along with apache's PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager for making API calls. The project in which I am working on requires setting custom timeout for each of the HTTP request I make via rest template. In order to achieve this, I am using CompletableFuture with a separate ExecutorService and calling get(Timeout) method.

```
    try{
        CompletableFuture<BidResponse> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> bidderService.getBid(), executorService);
        bidResponse = future.get(bidderTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
       } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException | ExecutionException e) {
            bidResponse = getTimeoutBidResponse();
       }
```

Unfortunately, the problem with this approach is that in cases of timeout, the underlying thread keeps on working until the rest template finishes its call. So I am kind of losing out a thread from the thread pool, as well as a connection from the HTTP connection pool. 
Is there a way to close the HTTP connection as soon as we receive a Timeout exception, and return the HTTP connection back to the pool ?

p.s. I also tried using Spring Webclient with Mono.timeout. Turns out it actually closes the HTTP connection immediately, but does not return it back to the HTTP pool.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) 
{
    return restTemplateBuilder
       .setConnectTimeout(...)
       .setReadTimeout(...)
       .build();
}
```